# Does every class need to be added to manifest?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
package com.example.uu.myapplication;

import android.app.Application;
import java.util.Locale;

public class GlobalClass extends Application 
{

     private Locale _slocale;

     public void setLocale(Locale loc) {
          _slocale=loc;
     }

     public Locale getLocale() {
          return  _slocale;
     }

}
```

Apart from every activity, do plain classes (as above) be needed to be added to AndroidManifest.xml? If so, then how?

Comment: No  no need to add classes in menifest file. But Activity must.

Comment: You've shown an Application class... The documentation says how to put that into the manifest.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: @cricket_007 So this application class needed to be added?

Comment: It's optional, but yes, if you want to use it, then you must add it. You don't make `new GlobalClass()` in your code, you can get it by casting `getApplicationContext()` (though you need a Context, like an Activity to call that method). People also will use the singleton pattern on the Application class, but I don't know if that is best practice or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to add those classes, which have a specific purpose, e.g. Activities. In your example, the GlobalClass inherits from Application. An app usually has a single Application Class that is referenced in the manifest file

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name="com.example.GlobalClass">
```

Is that really what you want to do?

I assume that you simply want to create classes that hold certain functionality. You can create them as plain Java Files and use them within your Activities, Fragments etc., and you can extend from them.

GlobalClass.java

```
 public class GlobalClass  {
     private Locale _slocale;

     public void setLocale(Locale loc)  {
         _slocale=loc;
     }

     public Locale getLocale() {
         return  _slocale;
     }
 }
```

SpecialClass.java

```
public class SpecialClass extends GlobalClass {
    public void doSomething() {
        Locale currentLocale = this.getLocale();
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a new class which calls some layout resources, you definitely add them to the Manifest.

That means you need to add activities to in the manifest. But not all classes.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to register: Activities, the Application class, Services, Receivers. Not all classes

Comment: & content providers (= application class & all [components](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html#Components))